# Python/OpenCV - Colored Droplets Recognition and Tracking

Tags: python, opencv, tracking

I'm a semi-noob in Video Analysis.
I have a Petri dish with some colored droplets inside and I must detect them, and keep trace of their position,area and color.

I want first to detect my Petri dish (maybe using HoughCircles) and define a ROI on which work later.

The problem is that mi dish detection is very "noisy": the program detects many circles (and I only need the one corresponding to the dish) and it never detects the right one.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def main():
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture("dropletsS.wmv")
    cv2.namedWindow("prova")
    while(1):
        ret, RGBframe = cap.read()
        grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(RGBframe,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grayFrame=cv2.medianBlur(grayFrame,7)
        circles=cv2.HoughCircles(grayFrame,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT ,50,50)
        for c in circles[0,:]:
            cv2.circle(RGBframe,(c[0],c[1]),c[2],(0,255,0),2)

        cv2.imshow("prova", RGBframe)
        cv2.imshow("grigio", grayFrame)
        cv2.waitKey(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img905/7286/zxVWiF.png) is the result.

Do someone have some suggestions? Suggestions on the way I can later identify and track droplets are welcome too.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of hard to come up with a solution without having much of an idea on how the dish actually looks like, but I'll try helping you anyways.

If the problem is what I think it is, then you can probably open and dilate your image to join all the discontinuous blobs.

Do the following before you apply Hough Transform:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5)) #declare outside while

grayFrame = cv2.morphologyEx(grayFrame, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
grayFrame = cv2.dilate(grayFrame, kernel, iterations = 2)
```

Let me know if the output is output image that you desire. Also play around with the parameters to get the required result. You can change the dimensions of the MORPH_ELLIPSE and also the number of iterations. Increasing any of them would increase the degree of dilation, thus more of the blobs would join up and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried to add the line codes that you suggested me but this is the result :
http://imageshack.com/a/img538/1489/FSB9aX.png

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to detect the circle as in the bigger circle in the image you posted along with the question. According to the image, its sure that the petri dish circle would be the one with the largest radius (or area). So you can work along these lines. You can find out the hough circle with the largest radius (or area) and use this for your ROI. Please ignore my previous answer.... I had a totally different image of a petri dish in mind :P